# Calling Rest API in Snow Flake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rest

How to Call rest Api call to notebook in Snowflake , As API call generates output files which are need to store in Snowflake itself

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're not supposed to call the Snowflake API directly. You do it through drivers and client tools as Polyakov has shown below

Answer (score 2):

you do not have to call an API directly from Snowflake. You can load files directly from your python notebook with a connection to Snowflake DB:

SQL code:

```sql
-- Create destination table to store your API queries results data
create or replace table public.tmp_table
    (page_id int,id int,status varchar,provider_status varchar,ts_created timestamp);

-- create a new format for your csv files
create or replace file format my_new_format type = 'csv' field_delimiter = ';' field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' skip_header = 1;

-- Put your local file to the Snowflake's temporary storage
put file:///Users/Admin/Downloads/your_csv_file_name.csv @~/staged;

-- Copying data from storage into table
copy into public.tmp_table from @~/staged/your_csv_file_name.csv.gz file_format = my_new_format ON_ERROR=CONTINUE;


select * from public.tmp_table;

-- Delete temporary data
remove @~/staged/tmp_table.csv.gz;
```

You can do the same with python:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#loading-data

```py
target_table = 'public.tmp_table'
filename = 'your_csv_file_name'
filepath = f'/home/Users/Admin/Downloads/{filename}.csv'
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    account=ACCOUNT,
    warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
    database=DATABASE,
    schema=SCHEMA
)
conn.cursor().execute(f'put file://{filepath} @~/staged;')

result = conn.cursor().execute(f'''
    COPY INTO {target_table}
    FROM @~/staged/{filename}.gz
    file_format = (format_name = 'my_new_format'
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE) ON_ERROR=CONTINUE;
''')
conn.cursor().execute(f'REMOVE @~/staged/{filename}.gz;')
```